# Where statement with decimal

Tags: sql

I'm creating a little project to manage money.

I have an option to filter the content in the `DataGrid` (the values are the ones that are in the database), one of the filtering options is to filter by amount of money but I have a problem. How I search using `decimal` values in `SQL`?

One `SQL query` that I use is:

```
Select qtd As 'Monetary amount' 
From mm_registos 
Where qtd > 10
```

But I want to filter using `decimal` values like:

```
Select qtd As 'Monetary amount' 
From mm_registos 
Where qtd > 10,8
```

Can anyone tell me the correct `query`?

Comment: It helps to say which SQL you are using. I guess that you should be using the English form of the decimal **10.8**

Comment: use point notation: 10.8

Comment: If you uses a parameterised query which you should be it would just work.

Comment: What is your default decimal separator? Your table data, what format the decimals are in? `10.8` or `10,8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the decimal separator. Try using `.`(i.e. write `Where qtd > 10.8`).

Answer (score 0):

SQL is tailored to the full-stop decimal notation.

[decimal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)